# Plotting against time(hh:mm) in R

Tags: r, time

I am trying to plot a .csv (located in my C:\R folder). The .csv has 2 columns, where the first 6 rows are headers and look something like this:

```
CSV-Export, 
, 
,SENS0700 
,28728 
TimeStamp,IntSolIrr 
hh:mm,W/m^2 
0:00,0.88 
0:05, 
0:20,0.6 
0:25,0.14 
0:30,0.25 
0:35,0.5 
0:40,0.25 
0:45,0.13
```

all the way to 23:55

If I were to type this

```
setwd("C:/R") 
testing=read.csv("testing.csv", skip=6, header = FALSE) 
plot(testing$V2)
```

I get a nice graph where every point is in order.

But when I try to plot the graph against time instead and type this

```
setwd("C:/R") 
testing=read.csv("testing.csv", skip=6, header = FALSE) 
plot(testing$V1, testing$V2)
```

The time gets all screwed up and the x-axis doesn't go from 0:00 to 23:55.

Is there a way to solve this? I also tried reading the documentation on zoo, but I cannot find how to tell R to treat only the first column as time in hh:mm format (I get a warning instead using read.zoo)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A beginner's mistake I made.

I should have done this instead:

```
setwd("C:/R") 
testing <- read.csv("testing.csv", skip=6, header = FALSE) 
testing$V1 <- strptime(testing$V1,format = "%H:%M") 
plot(testing$V1, testing$V2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ggplot2` library.

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(V1,V2, data=testing)
```

That should give you.

[image]

Comment: It seems that you posted the wrong script. At least it doesn't look like a `ggplot` script.

Comment: @Henrik thanks for noticing. Just the `q` from `qplot` was missing ;)

Comment: @geektrader I still get the same error. Here's a photo of what I'll get http://i74.photobucket.com/albums/i259/flee0308/wronggraph_zps21599b51.jpg?t=1380004132

Here's an image of what I get if I were to just use plot(testing$V2) 
http://i74.photobucket.com/albums/i259/flee0308/goodgraph_zps87646b7d.jpg

Comment: @user2809288 are you using `qplot` or `plot`? My answer suggests using `ggplot2` library's `qplot` function

Comment: @geektrader When using qplot, I receive an error

Error in ggplot(data, aesthetics, environment = env) : 
  object 'testing' not found